# jquery: when does $("???") scan the whole DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using `$("#xxx")` I guess under the hoods jQuery uses `getElementById`.

What about `$(".xxx")` does it scan the whole DOM every time?

Comment: jQuery probably doesn’t cache query results.

Comment: view the source here (click the big button): http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.js&downloadBtn=

Comment: oh, and jQuery uses the Sizzle selector engine nowadays. (both written by John Resig)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery attempts to use the fastest selection method to get what you asked for. There are a number of good resources with performance optimization tips out there that relate directly to jQuery:

[Good ways to improve jQuery selector performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214/good-ways-to-improve-jquery-selector-performance)

http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/quick-tip-optimizing-dom-traversal

Answer (score 4):

See the [`context` argument](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery) to the `$` function. If not supplied, it defaults to the entire `document`.

So to answer your question:

```
$('whatever'); // scans the entire `document`

$('whatever', element); // scans only within element
```

Comment: so this is basically like doing element.find('whatever') ?

Answer (score 1):

> What about $(".xxx") does it scan the whole DOM every time?

If you don't do the caching: yes. Caching is simple enough:

```
var $myCachedElements = $('.myElements'); // DOM querying occurs

$myCachedElements.animate({left: '1000px'}, 'slow'); // no DOM Querying this time, as long as you use the variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers do not support `getElementsByClassName` as a native DOM function, so jQuery has to do the work itself by checking each element's classes.

Comment: But it does try to use any Selector API method before gEBCN last I recall? Then the lowest common denominator is looping through each elements clsas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compatibility table for document.getElementsByClassName:  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements

The browsers in green for getElementsByClassName will *not* require a full DOM scan for $(".className") selectors, and will use browser-native methods instead.  The ones in red will be slower.

The difference isn't as pronounced as you'd think though, even for thousands of elements.