# jQuery cycle plugin customizing

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle, customizing

I'm using the jQuery Cycle plugin to start a slidshow of images when hovering over the initial image. This works fine. What I want after that is to have the slideshow stop when hovered off, and have a manual slideshow (next/prev buttons) start. This currently works, but the slideshow starts from the beginning each time it's initialized. I want it to begin at the current image that's loaded.

I was playing around with getting the image's index from the DOM (as it's the only one with display:block) and using the option 'startingSlide' to resume it, but my index keeps returning as -1.

```
jQuery('#home-menu li').hover(function()
{
   setImages(jQuery(this).attr('title'), jQuery(this).find('.subtitle').text());

   jQuery('#main .blog #projects .gallery .slideshow').cycle(
   {
      fx: 'scrollHorz',
      easing: 'easeOutBounce',
      speed: 2000,
      delay: 0
   });
}, function()
{
   // Before loading the images for the clickable slideshow, find the current image in the DOM array to use as the starting position
   slideshowStart = jQuery('.gallery .slideshow img:visible').index(this);
   console.log('Index: ' + slideshowStart);
   setImages(jQuery(this).attr('title'), jQuery(this).find('.subtitle').text());

   jQuery('#main .blog #projects .gallery .slideshow').cycle('stop').cycle(
   {
      fx: 'scrollHorz',
      easing: 'easeOutBounce',
      startingSlide: slideshowStart,
      speed: 2000,
      timeout: 0,
      next: "#main .blog #projects .gallery span.span2",
      prev: "#main .blog #projects .gallery span.span1"
   });
});
```

setImages() just loads images into the DOM based on what li is being hovered over. Nothing special there.

I want the image to be resumed when hovered over and hovered off. I've left out the resume part for hover on for the moment while I was trying to get it working - In case you were wondering.

Comment: This is in relation to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698727/jquery-element-index-in-array, btw

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the hover out callback:

```
slideshowStart = jQuery('.gallery .slideshow img:visible').index(this);
```

1) First, the jQuery statement selects all elements that match the selector. The cycle plugin ensures that only one image inside its container is displayed, so this satement  selects a maximum of one `img` element.

2) Second, the `index` function searches the elements selected in step 1 (the single `img` element) to see if it can find one that matches the *subject* (the argument provided to the index function). In your case, the subject is `this`, which in the context of the hover callback is `jQuery(#home-menu li)`.

`li` elements never match `img` elements, so this call to `index()` will always return -1 (for 'no object found').

To fix this, modify the statement like so:

```
slideshowStart = $('.slideshow img').index($('img:visible'));
```

1) First, this selects all the `img` elements in your `<div class='slideshow'>` element.

2) Second, it returns the index of the first visible `img` element in that list.

Comment: Still returning -1. I've tried changing it up to be `var slideshowStart = jQuery('.gallery .slideshow').find('img[style*="display: hidden"]').index(this);`. Still -1. I've been using 'this' inside index() as per pretty much site I've found on Google has said. I can't seem to get this to return anything but -1

Comment: I'm off to bed, but you should post the relevant html as well, which should help others figure this out.

Comment: HTML: `<div id="parent">
   <div class="gallery">
      <span class="span1">&#9668;</span><span class="span2">&#9658;</span>
      <div class="slideshow">
         <img src="initial image" />
      </div>
   </div>

   <span class="description" style="font-style: italic"></span>
</div>`

The images are added into the .slideshow via jQuery. I managed to get an index by using `slideshowStart = jQuery('*').index(jQuery('.gallery .slideshow .img:visible'));` but it's into the hundreds when there's only 5 images. So I'm guessing I need to replace '*' with .slideshow to reduce the index?

Comment: That's close. If you replace '*' with '.slideshow', you won't be able to find any matches for '.gallery .slideshow .img:visible', because you're already inside the slideshow div. That is the context for the index function's search, and the slideshow div doesn't contain any elements with the gallery or slideshow classes (much less a visible img inside a .slideshow element inside a .gallery element, which is what you're instructing the index function to find). I've updated my answer with a solution that works (and actually tested this time D: ).

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want it to pause and play, use the options:

```
jQuery('#home-menu li').hover(function() {
  $("#yourSlideshow").cycle("resume");
}, function {
  $("#yourSlideshow").cycle("pause");
});
```