# How do I select more than one element using the jQuery attribute selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two elements that I would like to select

```
<input id="iMe" /> and <span id="sMe">Blah</span>
```

I would like to select them both:

```
$("span[id$='Me']") and $("input[id$='Me']")
```

in one selector.  I've tried:

```
$("span,input[id$='Me']") -> Nope
$("span[id$='Me'],input[id$='Me']") -> Nope
$("span[id$='Me']input[id$='Me']") -> Nope
```

I wouldn't mind just adding it to the collection either.  I definitely don't want to create more script to hack around this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example page: http://jsbin.com/idali (view/edit source at http://jsbin.com/idali/edit)

The following variations should all work:

```
$("span[id$=Me], input[id$=Me]")
$('span[id$=Me], input[id$=Me]')
$("span[id$='Me'], input[id$='Me']")
$('span[id$="Me"], input[id$="Me"]')
```

(edit: the original answer below is wrong; quotes are optional but allowed...)

<strike>You've got too much quoting in your attempts... You want</strike>

```
$("span[id$=Me],input[id$=Me]")
```

Attribute values are not quoted in css selectors.

Comment: $("span[id$=Me],input[id$=Me]"); throwing an error...how wierd.  I believe you, I'm just confused why the heck it's throwing the error.

Comment: Unexpected call to method or property access.

Comment: Also just a FYI: From jQuery docs Quotes are optional in most cases, but should be used to avoid conflicts when the value contains characters like "]".  So i don't think the quotes are doing it.

Comment: The error I'm seeing isn't the selector, it's trying to set the text of both of them later.

Comment: @rball: Yeah, I read the docs for quotes shortly before you pointed that out... I've never used them before, but I can see where they might be needed. As to your issue, if you're trying to set the text using the `$.text()` method, that might be your problem; I think (haven't checked) that you're supposed to use `$.value()` for text-input controls...

Answer (score 4):

Why not give the two elements a class?

```
<input class="frobbable" id="iMe" /> and <span class="frobbable" id="sMe">Blah</span>
```

then

```
$(".frobbable")
```

?

Comment: Crap, the asp.net hidden field doesn't have a cssClass property.  Yah!  :(

Comment: Well, I don't know what asp.net is, but if it's something that hides HTML from you, it's broken by design.

Comment: I am not sure that could be bug, but it doesn't work for .on(), event delegate only first selected element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span[id$=Me]').add('input[id$=Me]')
```

Comment: Tried $("span[id$='Me']").add("input[id$='Me']"); threw a js error.

Comment: Full line: $component = $("span[id$=Me]").add("input[id$=Me]"); no dice

Comment: my answer and $('span[id$=Me], input[id$=Me]')  both DO work with your example code. you're leaving something out of your question

Comment: are you maybe forgetting to include the jquery script library ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#iMe, span#sMe');
```

Comment: asp.net so I'm matching the ends, that's why I have an attribute selector

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[id$='Me']")
```

should work. But watch out for the performance as this will have to go through the entire DOM.

Comment: Tried that, it literally froze the browser.  Also tried *[id$=Me].

Comment: Looks like your DOM is too complex. Try to descend from a parent with an id selector, something like - `$("#parentDiv").find("[id$='Me']")`

Comment: Few tips http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214/good-ways-to-improve-jquery-selector-performance http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span[id$='Me'],input[id$='Me']") -> Yep
```

This really should work as well as the add() method, so maybe you have a problem somewhere else? Some ancient version of jQuery perhaps?