# Can I combine jQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to do the following:

```
$("#dat_chk" + (i)).css("background-color", "#f6FFee");
$("#dat_opt" + (i)).css("background-color", "#f6FFee");
$("#dat_txt" + (i)).css("background-color", "#f6FFee");
```

Is these way I can shorten to just one select with jQuery?

Comment: is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752718/how-do-i-select-more-than-one-element-using-the-jquery-attribute-selector ?

Comment: separate the selectors using commas and you can use it within a single jquery statement

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#dat_chk" + i + ", #dat_opt" + i + ", #dat_txt" + i).css("background-color", "#f6ffee");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var selector = '#dat_chk' + i + ', #dat_opt' + i + ', #dat_txt' + i;

$(selector).css("background-color", "#f6FFee");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#dat_chk" + i + ", #dat_opt" + i + ", #dat_txt" + i).css("background-color", "#f6FFee");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Seperate them with a `,`:

```
$("#dat_chk" + (i) + ", #dat_opt" + (i) + ", #dat_txt" + (i)).css("background-color", "#f6FFee");
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as using the comma separator, you can also use [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
      $("#dat_chk" + i)
   .add("#dat_opt" + i)
   .add("#dat_txt" + i)
   .css( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

the selector should look like this:

```
$( "#dat_chk" + i +  ", #dat_opt" + i + ", #dat_txt" + i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy buddy:

```
$("#dat_chk" + (i) + ", #dat_opt" + (i) + ", #dat_txt" + (i)).css("background-color", #f6FFee");
```

Like this example - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/zNu3W/

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.class').css("background-color", "#f6FFee");
```