# Problem with :contains selector in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on the following selector in jQuery:

```
$("div[id^=WebPartWPQ]:has(table.ms-sitedirresultssort) td:contains(' : ')").closest('div')
```

In other words: select the div with ID starting with `WebPartWPQ` that has a table with class `ms-sitedirresultssort` that has a td containing the text `:`. At the end of this question is the HTML rendered by SharePoint.

The selector works perfectly under Firefox 3.5, however not under Internet Explorer 8. I'm testing by using the `hide()` function.

I've narrowed it down to the `td:contains(' : ')` part of the selector. Running `$("td:contains(' : ')")` in Firebug Lite dumps out a whole list of functions like something isn't valid. All the other selectors work fine in FB Lite.

I've tried using jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery 1.4rc1 without success. Is this a bug in jQuery and if so is there a ticket for it (I can't find one)? Any ideas on how to best get around this?

HTML:

```
<div style="" helpmode="1" helplink="/_layouts/help.aspx" allowdelete="false" class="ms-WPBody"
    width="100%" id="WebPartWPQ4" haspers="false" webpartid="2ae67b12-82db-4238-8be9-cd4b39cbd15a">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" xmlns:crwp="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:CategoryResultsWebPart"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        class="ms-sitedirresultssort">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" />
                <td nowrap="">
                    <a href="#title">Sort by Title </a><span>| </span><a href="#url">Sort by Url </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" xmlns:crwp="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:CategoryResultsWebPart"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        class="ms-sitedirresultspaging">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> : </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" xmlns:crwp="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:CategoryResultsWebPart"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        class="ms-sitedirresultsbody" id="table2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <img alt="" src="/_layouts/images/lstbulet.gif" />
                </td>
                <td width="100%" class="ms-sitedirresultstitle">
                    <a href="http://site/cd10/_layouts/mysite.aspx?Redirect=1">Setup MySite</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td />
                <td width="100%" class="ms-sitedirresultsurl">
                    <a dir="ltr" href="http://site/cd10/_layouts/mysite.aspx?Redirect=1">http://site/cd10/_layouts/mysite.aspx?Redirect=1</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<td>
    :
</td>
```

Doesn't contain `:` in either browser, as the trailing newline is different to a space. However:

```
<td> : </td>
```

now does give different results in IE and Firefox. The `contains` doesn't match in IE, because its parser has silently thrown away the whitespace, as IE likes to do. If you look at the `innerHTML` you see:

```
<TD>: </TD>
```

Which unsurprisingly doesn't match the selector.

So be careful with `contains` and whitespace because IE's HTML parser is as quirky as ever.

Personally I'd try to avoid non-standard jQuery selectors like `:has` and particularly `:contains`, as they require jQuery to do a lot of slow work. Standard CSS2-3 selectors, on the other hand, can be passed off to the browser's own selector engine in newer browsers with Selectors-API support (including IE8).

How about something like:

```
$('.ms-sitedirresultssort ~ table td').filter(function() {
    return this.text().match(/(^|\s):(\s|$)/);
})
```

`~` is a CSS3 selector for any-following-sibling; IE8 does support it.

Comment: I prettified the HTML for posting it here which altered the spacing around the `<td>`. Whoops! Thanks for answering given my mistake anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case, but it seems possible that the issue may be to do with whitespace... for example if I try the html you provided & try to select with `$("td:contains(' : ')")` (in Firefox), I get no matches, because the content of the `td` you're trying to match is actually something like: `<td>\n....:\n.....</td>` (with `.` for spaces & `\n` for new lines). In other words it doesn't contain `' : '` because of the newline (selecting on `' :'` works though). So its just a guess, but maybe IE8 does some clean up of the raw whitespace when creating its DOM tree, meaning that your `' : '` selector isn't matching properly.

So assuming there'll be other `td`'s with `:`'s in them & you're just after the `td` with the single `:` (padded with random whitespace), you could use a slightly less specific selector & then filter that down functionally like this:

```
$("div[id^=WebPartWPQ]:has(table.ms-sitedirresultssort) td:contains(':')")
    .filter(function() { return $.trim($(this).text()) == ":"; })
    .closest('div');
```

Not quite as clean & probably a little slower, but might be a suitable work around.

Comment: I messed up the HTML in the question by prettifying it. But your suggestion is still valid, thanks!