# jQuery Failure to Uncheck Checkboxes Programmatically

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click, toggle

Simple functionality, I want to toggle checking/unchecking checkboxes based on changing a top level checkbox.

The problem is that Toggle/Click event handlers have inherent issues.  If you try to bind these handlers to an input checkbox, the default checking behavior of the box fails.

So, I tried to use the Change handler in one of two different ways.

```
     $('input.all_neighborhoods').change(function(){
    if($(this).not(':checked')){
        $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').find('input[name=neighborhood_id]').attr('checked','checked');
    }
    else{
        $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').find('input[name=neighborhood_id]').removeAttr('checked');
    }

    });
```

Here, the first change works as you'd expect.  All sibling checkboxes are selected and checked.  However, when I click again to uncheck, nothing happens.  The event handler doesn't work.

I then tried this:

```
   $('input.all_neighborhoods').change(function(){
    $(this).attr( 'checked', $(this).is( ':checked' ) ? $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').find('input[name=neighborhood_id]').attr('checked','checked'): $(this).removeAttr('checked').closest('li').siblings('li').find('input[name=neighborhood_id]').removeAttr('checked') );
});
```

Here, the sibling checkboxes effectively toggle.  However, the main on/off switch checkbox stays checked.

Is the issue here related to the fact that they are all siblings and the main checkbox is not the parent?

Comment: Hey Brendan, perhaps you could provide some of the HTML markup as well - I'm having a hard time visualizing what is going on without seeing the structure. If you have a live link as well, that would make it really easy to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Warning, shameless self-promotion ahead). I've written a jQuery plugin that handles all of this messiness for you. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Check it out: http://mjball.github.com/jQuery-CheckAll/

---

If you want to stick with your current method, here's how to fix it:

```
$('input.all_neighborhoods').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('li')
        .siblings('li')
        .find('input[name=neighborhood_id]').attr('checked', this.checked);
}
```

Just pass a boolean to `.attr()`. Also, as per [When to use Vanilla JavaScript vs. jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/) don't use

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

Instead use

```
this.checked
```

It's fewer characters to write, doesn't require any jQuery, and is *way* more efficient.

Comment: I got sick of writing the master/slave logic after the 3rd time or so, and it was really not much work to turn it into a plugin.

Comment: Ahhh, I wish I could just do this without a plugin. I will try this out though, thanks Matt

Comment: @Bredan: you _can_ do it without a plugin. The plugin just makes it nicely encapsulated and reusable. The actual code is < 100 lines - that includes lots of whitespace and [Allman-style indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style) - so you should be able to go through the code and understand what it does.

Comment: Brilliant. Also, thanks for the link, I'm a noob and am trying to figure out efficiency as I go