# Why I can not get the row id when mouse clicked on a table row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a ***index.html*** page with a table:

```
<body>
      <table class="mytable">
          <tr id="1">
              <td>John</td>
              <td>123</td>
          </tr>
           <tr id="2">  
              <td>Kate</td>
              <td>456</td>
          </tr>
      </table>

  <script src="my.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I have included ***my.js*** in my page, I tried to get the **id** of the mouse clicked row in the following way in ***my.js***:

```
$('.mytable tr').click(function(e){
                   alert('clicked.'); //even did not get alert here.
                   var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
               alert(rowId);
        });
```

But I did not get the row id of clicked row(no alert), where am I wrong?

**---Solution---**

My bad, I have one place emptied the table, which means no tr at all. that's why it does not work. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: have you tried alert and see if you're getting that to bubble up?

Comment: I don't understand... Is this a Firebug problem or jQuery problem? Can you try an "alert(rowId)" to see if it works?

Comment: @Joseph, yes, I tried alert also, but nothing happened.

Comment: Then I'd say the problem is something to do with your event handler not bubbling correctly somehow.

Comment: make sure that you've placed `<script src="my.js'>` below `<script src ="jQuery.js">` because scripts are executed in order in which the appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `$ === jQuery` ?
2. Is the code which binds the click listener executed in a [document ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)?
3. [`this.id` is sufficient and will work in all browsers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery)

Comment: I have updated my post, I even did not get the alert  alert('clicked.');

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Is the path to the JS file correct?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine...  Here's a working JSFiddle that uses alert instead of console.log:

http://jsfiddle.net/gfosco/KtYkJ/

Based on the comments and Matt's answer, you should wrap your function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mytable tr').click(function(e){
               var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
           alert(rowId);
    });
});
```

The javascript was executing before the DOM was ready and therefore the handler was not being applied.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, I just found the reason, check my updates

Answer (score 1):

[It's working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/nNZuH/).

What *do* you get if not the id?

The most common problem is that the event handler isn't binding to the element, for which the most common solution is to wrap it in `$(document).ready(){ ... }` so that it waits for the DOM to load before binding to elements.

(There's also the relatively recent `.live()` function which [binds to elements as they get added in the life of the document](http://api.jquery.com/live/).)

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, I just found the reason, check my updates

Answer (score 1):

first you must check your js file path that it is correct or not?
if this is correct then i think there is no any error in your script ..
i also tested it ... you can check it
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chhameed/Cbj6h/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your event handler to

```
$('.mytable tr').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var rowId = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(rowId);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, I just found the reason, check my updates