# Ajax see the old class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've this:

```
$(".follow").click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("id");
        var data = "id=" + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "follow.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                element.removeClass("follow");
                element.addClass("unfollow");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(".unfollow").click(function() {
        alert("Hey, dude");
    });
```

When I click on my button I can see with Firebug the class switch. But if I try to click the button again, it doesn't appear the alert, the script send always the POST request to follow.php.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.live('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead of `.click(...)`. The former works for all elements matching that selector, now *and in the future*, whereas the latter only works for elements matching the selector *right now*.

It's not a matter of ajax "seeing" the old class, it's how the event listeners are bound. `$(".follow").click(callback)` finds all the elements in the DOM that have the class `follow`, and then binds `callback` to the `click` event of every such element. Removing the `follow` class does not remove event listeners.

`.live()` also binds only one listener, rather than one listener per element in the jQuery object, so it is more "efficient" (read: lighter weight) in that regard.

```
$(".follow").live("click", function() {
    var element = $(this),
        data = "id=" + this.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "follow.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(result) {
            element.removeClass("follow").addClass("unfollow");
        }
    });

    return false;
});

$(".unfollow").live("click", function() {
    alert("Hey, dude");
});
```

#### Notes

- You can, and should, use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")`. See [When to use Vanilla JavaScript vs. jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/)
- Take advantage of jQuery's chainability for more efficient, concise code.

Comment: +1 Very thank you, man. You rocks our boats. Thank you also for your notes!