# jQuery $(this).val returns 0

Tags: jquery

I have a simple list like this:

```
<ul id="large_box_custom_list">
<li id="8" class="large_box">Item 1</li>
<li id="13" class="large_box">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

then I have a jQuery function like this:

```
$(function() { 
$('li.large_box').css('cursor', 'pointer')
.click(function() {
    var show_id = $(this).val();
    alert(show_id);
    });
});
```

When I click the list items my alery shows a value of 0 when I am expecting a value of 8 or 13.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you should be using the [standard DOM element `id` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Properties). jQuery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method has **nothing** to do with an element's ID.

```
$('li.large_box').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function ()
{
    var show_id = this.id;
    alert(show_id);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`val()` doesn't return the id. You want `$(this).attr('id')` instead.

Comment: jQuery is completely unnecessary; `this.id` is sufficient. See comments on other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

the `id` attribute is meant to be used as a unique identifier, not as a means of data-storage.

Additionally, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is meant to be used on `input, select, textarea` elements to access their current values.

If you need an element's attribute use the [`.attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

If you need to store data on an element, use a custom HTML5 `data-` element:

```
<li data-id="8"...
<li data-id="13"...
```

You'd then be able to access the value with the [`.data()` function](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
var listItemIdentifier = $(this).data('id');
console.log( listItemIdentifier );
//should output 8 or 13 depending on which you click on
```

Comment: `.prop()` should be used instead of `.attr()` in most cases nowadays.

Comment: @MattBall, good point if you're working in `1.6+`. I often have to work in slightly older versions of jQuery so I've been using `attr` out of habit.

Comment: Properties and attributes should not be treated interchangeably even if JQuery allows them to be. Think of properties as boolean attributes which tend to have the same name and value `selected="selected"` or `checked="checked"`.

Comment: @AlienWebguy, i'm very well aware of that, I used to use `$(...).is(':selected')` and `$(...).is(':checked')` as a safe way of checking. I use `attr` when I need the *actual* attribute value.

Comment: Yea my comment was actually for Matt :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `attr()` instead of `val()`:

```
$(function() { 
    $('li.large_box').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        var show_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(show_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: `.attr()` is complete overkill for getting an element's ID (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923). -1

Comment: So you downvote a legitimate answer? It looks like he's trying to learn jQuery, so I showed him how to do it in jQuery.

Comment: Just because you can access the id attribute in JQuery does not mean that is how you should reference the id.

Comment: Matt, I didn't use your way but I appreciate your answer since I am indeed new to jQuery and javascript altogether.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this).attr('id')`

`<li>` can't have a value with out using non standard attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var show_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

A id attribute is not a value attribute.

You can either set it up to get the id:

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

Or set the value in HTML

```
<li id="8" value="8" class="large_box">Item 1</li>
```

Here is a live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BBm4R/