# jQuery : show div by dynamic id

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="service-chooser" id="ubuntu-one">Ubuntu One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="service-chooser" id="ftp">FTP account</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- these div are hidden -->
<div id="ubuntu-one-form" class="hide">
    Ubuntu One credential
</div>
<div id="ftp-form" class="hide">
    Ftp Crediental
</div>
```

when i click on a link i want to show a div based on the id of the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".service-chooser").click(function() {
    var service = $(this).attr('id');
    var service-id = '#' + service + 'form';

      $(service-id).show('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });

    });

});

</script>
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variable names in JavaScript cannot contain a `-`. When you open your console, you should have received an error, similar to `missing ; before statement`.

Valid characters for a variable name are alphanumeric characters, underscore and dollar sign.

You can fix your code by replacing the `-` by a `_`:

```
$(".service-chooser").click(function() {
    var service = this.id           ;           // Example ubuntu-one
    var service_id = '#' + service + '-form';   // Example #ubuntu-one-form

      $(service_id).show('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

I have also replaced `$(this).attr('id')` by `this.id`.
See also: [When to use Vanilla JavaScript vs. jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Your service id also needs to concat a '-' as per your html (`<div id="ubuntu-one-form" class="hide">`), also your service-id should be service_id:

```
$(".service-chooser").click(function() {
    var service = $(this).attr('id');
    var service_id = '#' + service + '-form';
```

Answer (score 0):

Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/T887t/ Don't have a `-` in your variable name, and you forgot to add the `-` when adding the id of the `a` to the variable.