# Noob jquery error when two items have the same id

Tags: jquery

This works fine but when I have two sliders, the javasctript causes problems because both have the same id "range". How can I modify the js to allow two sliders to be on the same page? Thanks

```
<li>
<label for="budget">Budget*</label>
<input type="range" min="1000" max="10000" value="2000" step="1000" onchange="showValue(this.value)">
<span id="range">$2000</span>

<script>
  function showValue(newValue)
  {
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
  }
</script>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use classes instead of ids.

Also, do not mix vanilla JavaScript with jQuery in this way. If you are using jQuery use it anywhere you will <strike>interact with</strike> manipulate the DOM.

1. **HTML**:

```
<li>
    <label for="budget">Budget*</label>
    <input type="range" min="1000" max="10000" value="2000" step="1000">
    <span class="range">$2000</span>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="budget">Budget*</label>
    <input type="range" min="1000" max="10000" value="2000" step="1000">
    <span class="range">$2000</span>
</li>
```

2. **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="range"]').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $li = $this.closest('li');
        $li.find('span.range').text('$'+$this.val());
    });
});
```

3. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/P39xB/)

Comment: I take serious issue with the last two sentences. There are absolutely times when it is appropriate to use vanilla JS instead of jQuery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery

Comment: I agree. Vanilla JS is vital when developing any jQuery website.  Maybe not in the scenario above, but there are tons of times when it is applicable.

Comment: @MattBall & Switz: I should have made the statement more clear, but what I was saying is that if you want to manipulate the DOM use jQuery. I agree with you, it is inefficient and overuse when you just need to retrieve from an element you already have a reference of.

Comment: This works except how do I modify it If I want the second slider to be in some other type of units (e.g "weeks" instead of "$")

Comment: @user852974 Add the unit on another span element, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/P39xB/).

Answer (score 4):

Two Items should **never** have the same id.  That's what classes are for.

Also, if you're using jQuery, you can condense this code to:

`$("#range").html(newValue);`

Comment: +1 for clear statement, and for pointing out that the OP wasn't using jQuery in the code he showed us.