# jQuery UI Highlight Footnotes Without onclick Events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, highlight

I am using the jQuery UI Highlight effect to highlight one of many (>20) footnotes because they can easily fill an average screen once directed there. I am passing the footnote number as a value of a function with an onclick event. I am sure there is a more elegant way of implementing this without those cluttering up the HTML, but I am a relatively new to JS...

```
function highlighter(footnote_number) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li[id="footnote' + footnote_number + '"]').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    });
};
```

Footnotes within the text:

```
<a id="footnote_a1" href="#footnote1" onclick="highlighter('1')">1</a>
```

direct to:

```
<div id="footnotes">
    <ol>
        <li id="footnote_a1">
            (Footnote)
           <a href="#footnote1">&uarr;</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take the $(document).ready() method out of the function:

```
function highlighter(footnote_number) {
    $('li[id="footnote' + footnote_number + '"]').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Woudlnt it be simpler to write...?

```
$('#footnote' + footnote_number).effect(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through every anchor with a class of footnote and bind the click() event to highlight your footnotes.

```
$(function(){
  $('ol').find('a.footnote').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    $(this).bind('click', function(){
      $('div#footnotes li#' + id).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, though I found .find() unnecessary, using a selector instead.  And used an anchor's href attribute to reference the appropriate li by id:

`$(function(){
 $('a[id^="footnote"]').each(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).bind('click', function(){
   $(id).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
     })
 })
});`

Comment: `$(this).id` is completely unnecessary. `this.id` works across browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery