# Override parrents onClick event with checkbox onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, sorry for my bad English.

I'm making a Coupons site and have trouble with selecting and deselecting the coupons. Each coupon is in a DIV 'box' in which there is a checkbox.

I made a onClick function on the DIV box (so the user can select the coupon by clicking on anything inside the DIV box. What I need now is, when the user want to deselect the coupon (by clicking on the checkbox inside the DIV box), I need to 'override' the DIV's onClick function (execute the checkbox onClick event, not the DIV's onClick event).

I know that everyone prefers some code as an example, but the question/problem is simple and I don't think you need all of my un'useless code inside the events/functions :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Code samples almost always make helping easier. That being said, have you looked into using jQuery's stopPropagation on the checkboxes? http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want `stopPropagation` if the checkbox is being unchecked: http://jsfiddle.net/8Dcq8/.

```
$("div").click(function() {
    alert("add"); // clicking anywhere in div to add coupon
});

$(":checkbox").click(function(e) {
    if(!this.checked) { // if unchecking, remove coupon
        alert("remove");
        e.stopPropagation(); // don't run parent onclick
    }
});
```

Comment: Ugh, no. `$(this).is(":checked")` is completely excessive. [All you need is `this.checked`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4652402/139010).

Answer (score 1):

If the `<div>` click handler looks something like this:

```
var $boxes = $('div.box');
$boxes.on('click', function ()
{
    // do whatever to select the coupon
});
```

Then the checkbox handler should look something like this:

```
$boxes.find('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function (event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    // do whatever to deselect the coupon
});
```

See [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel bubbling. See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link9) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery Alternative, or create sub-elements with onClicks that don't target your checkbox. you might be able to use something like this also.

```
document.getElementById('element').checked.onreadystatechange=function(){
//code

}
```

good luck