# change the href attrb on hovring the imag using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i want to go to this image using jquery or javascript and then on hover the image change the  href attrb to another src image

this is the code :

```
<a href="Sign-Up.aspx" ><img alt="Login" src="images/login3.png" style="width: 173px; margin-top: 0px; z-index:10;" /></a>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty easy using the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) methods.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's give ourselves a way of identifying this anchor/image combo from anything else in your page:

```
<a class="button" href="Sign-Up.aspx" ><img alt="Login"
  src="images/login3.png"
  style="width: 173px; margin-top: 0px; z-index:10;" /></a>
```

Then let's write some jQuery to swap the images:

```
$('a.button img').mouseover(
    function() { $(this).attr('src', 'images/login3_hover.png'); }
);
$('a.button img').mouseout(
    function() { $(this).attr('src', 'images/login3.png'); }
);
```

The second bit ensuring we get back to the original state when not hovering.

However you don't actually need Javascript for this; you can instead do it using just CSS and HTML. To achieve this you have to separate the text and the image of the link. Something like the following HTML:

```
<a class='button' href="Sign-Up.aspx"><b>Login</b></a>
```

with some CSS:

```
a.button {
    width: 173px;
    height: 73px; // or whatever your image height is
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("images/login3.png");
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}

a.button:hover {
    background-image: url("images/login3_hover.png");
}
a.button b {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

(I've omitted the `margin-top` and `z-index` rules, since they're presumably dependent on other things going on in your page.)

What we're doing there is attaching the image to the anchor as a CSS background image, and then changing it when we're hovering over that anchor. The text (which was previously in the `alt` attribute for the image) is then styled so that it doesn't show (but is still available for search engines and accessibility tools).

There's still a problem with both those solutions, however, because the `images/login3_hover.png` image won't be loaded before you hover, so you'll get a brief flash of whatever the background colour behind the anchor is while it loads. To solve this, you need to use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), which builds on the `background-image` technique above.

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to your image tag, E.G id="image", then add this javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#image').hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/new_image.png');
    });
});
```

Comment: `src` instead of `href`. `this.src = 'images/new_image.png';` instead of `$(this).attr(...)` is better though.

Comment: @RobW thanx, I changed it to src. When using jQuery I think it's better using $(this).attr(). Another option is to preload the images, through var rollover = new Image; rollover.src = 'images/rollover.png'; Then you can just use $(this).attr('src', rollover.src);

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. Anything which is readable and well-supported in JavaScript does not have to be written in jQuery. For a list of many examples, see [When to use vanilla JavaScript vs jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery).

Comment: @RobW I agree, I'm just so used to using jQuery for everything, I never actually think about using plain javascript for the most obvious things