# jQuery each() returns only first found value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the IDs from my parent divs

```
<div id="btn1"><label class="btn"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></label></div>
<div id="btn2"><label class="btn"><input type="button" value="Add"/></label></div>
```

jQuery function:

```
$('.btn').each(function () {
    alert($('.btn').parent().attr("id"));
});
```

The function returns the value 'btn1' two times. It should return 'btn1', 'btn2'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a selector for `.btn` again inside your loop.  Change it to refer to the current element using `this`

```
$('.btn').each(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Edit:

As per [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00)

> there really is no reason to use three jQuery function calls here.
>   jQuery should be used only when it does the job better.

And a reference for some of these common scenarios:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4652402/803739

Comment: `$(this).parent().attr("id")` can be replaced with the something much, much faster and more compact `this.parentNode.id`.  There really is no reason to use three jQuery function calls here.  jQuery should be used only when it does the job better.

Comment: If you want to get really technical there are lots of things wrong with his code, like `input`s nested in `label`s, etc.  I just directly answered his question.

Comment: And, I suggested code that would make a better answer.  You don't need to be defensive.  You could incorporate the suggestion into your answer.  I thought about posting a competing answer, but decided to try to get you to improve yours.  Besides it's a pet peeve of mine when anyone (the OP in this case and then copied by you) uses jQuery in places where it's the inefficient way to do things.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to sound defensive or hostile.  I guess I'm just used to ignoring technicalities like that when I see OPs with < 10 rep.  I always assume they are just asking to get a quick answer and will generally ignore proper ways of doing things anyways. Appending your suggestion along with a reference for similar cases for future readers.