# Using more than 1 val in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is probably a very simple solution to this but my jQuery skills are not yet up to much.
I am using the below to show and hide a div based on the valus on a dropdown. I would like to adapt it so both "No" and "" will work.
How do i achive this?

Thanks in advance

```
$('#q1').change(function(){
 if ($(this).val() == "No") {
 $('#divv').show();
 } else {
 $('#divv').hide();
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways. Personally I'd do this:

```
if( this.value.match(/(No)?/i)) {
```

The `i` allows `NO`, `no` and `nO` to also work - remove it if you only want "No".

Comment: This was going to be a later question about the case, thank you very much!

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as Accepted by clicking the check mark underneath the vote score.

Comment: No reason. I just prefer to use `match` since it's similar to `preg_match` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript [logical or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C)) (`||`) in this case:

```
$('#q1').change(function() {
    value = this.value;
    if (value == "No" || value == "") {
        $('#divv').show();
    } else {
        $('#divv').hide();
    }
}
);
```

Actually the most adaptable solution would be this: `if (value.toLowerCase() == "no" || value == "") {` This would accept "No" no matter what case it's in.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/YKeFy/1/

**EDIT:** Updated code to satisfy Kolink and Bergi

Comment: Inefficient due to creating the same `$(this)` object twice.

Comment: http://w3fools.com/ - especially for logical operators, there are much better references

Comment: @Kolink Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down very carefully, you virtually, and maybe literally, downvoted every answer but your own.

Comment: @A.M.K I had reasons to downvote them. This one because of the object inefficiency, but I see that's now been fixed. Now my downvote is there because of the `value == "null"`, which I have no idea why it's there...

Comment: I mistakenly thought that if a dropdown item had no value then it would return null, I tested and removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript OR operator (`||`):

```
$('#q1').change(function(){
 var thisVal = $(this).val();
 if ((thisVal == "No") || (thisVal == "")) {
 $('#divv').show();
 } else {
 $('#divv').hide();
 }
 });
```

Comment: Inefficient due to creating the same `$(this)` object twice.

Comment: @Kolink - could you please explain a little further as to how referencing `this` is more inefficient than a variable ?

Comment: Creating an entire jQuery object around `this` is what's inefficient.

Comment: @Kolink `$(this)` object is only created once now, then referenced twice :)

Comment: Now you're calling the `val()` function on it twice.

Comment: @Kolink Not as costly as calling `$(this)` twice, but fair enough.. I've changed that too. This is just an example of using the `||` operator though really, not a lesson in performance.

Answer (score 0):

The [logical `OR` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) should do:

```
$('#q1').change(function(){
    if (this.value == "No" || this.value == "") {
        $('#divv').show();
    } else {
        $('#divv').hide();
    }
});
```

I have not used `$(this)` (especially not twice) to create jQuery objects, but just used [plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651923/1048572). Even more concise, if you want (using a [tertiary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), the [not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)) to check for an empty string and [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)):

```
$('#q1').change(function(){
    $('#divv')[ (this.value == "No" || !this.value) ? "show" : "hide" ]();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle()` and set the state to show or hide by checking the value with a regex.

```
$('#q1').on('change', function(){
    $('#divv').toggle(this.value.match(/(no|^$)/i));
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kvqFw/1/)    ​

Answer (score -1):

copy and Paste this, this should work.

```
$('#q1').change(function(){
 if (($(this).val() == "No") || ($(this).val() == "")) {
 $('#divv').show();
 } else {
 $('#divv').hide();
 }
 });
```