# Get values out of an array and create for each value a variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables

I have this html:

```
<div id="h101" data-stellar-ratio="6"><img src="images/h1_01.png" width="600"></div>
<div id="cloud01" data-stellar-ratio="0.5"><img src="images/cloud_01-s.png"></div>
<div id="cloud02" data-stellar-ratio="0.4"><img src="images/cloud_01-s.png"></div>
<div id="island01" data-stellar-ratio="2"><img src="images/island_01.png" width="620"></div>
```

I create an array from all the id's

```
$(".section > div").each(function() {
ellementArray.push($(this).attr("id"));});
```

Now I have all the values in my ellementArray.
What I want to do is to create this:

```
var h101Left = $("#h101").position().left;
var cloud01Left = $("#cloud01").position().left;
var island02Left = $("#island02").position().left;
var island03Left = $("#island03").position().left;
```

I was thinking something like this...

```
for (var i = 0; i < ellementArray.length; i++){
        jQuery.globalEval("var ellementArray[i] = ellementArray[i];")
        console.log(ellementArray[i]);
    }
```

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. Just create a map from string (the element ID) to number (the  position-left value):

```
var leftPositions = {};
$(".section > div").each(function ()
{
    leftPositions[this.id] = $(this).position().left;
});
```

---

BTW, if you still need an array of all the IDs, use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) instead of `.each()`, and [`this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery):

```
var elementArray = $(".section > div").map(function ()
{
    return this.id
}).get();
```

Comment: Good solution, but then my output will be: h101 = 200; What i need is h101left = 200...

Comment: Okay, so change `leftPositions[this.id]` to `leftPositions[this.id + 'left']`. Not rocket science.