# ID of draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I want to get the id of the div i am moving.
I have tried different methods, nothing worked. 
So why isn't this working?

```
$('#content').children().draggable({
drag: function (event, ui) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#textarea').val(id);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pX2T4/

Comment: [The code is fine. **Your draggable div does not have an ID.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/JfRPX/) And just an FYI, `this.id` can always be used instead of `$(this).attr('id')`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4651923/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because $(this) is refering to the inner div marked with the class

see http://jsfiddle.net/pX2T4/

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="content" id="foo">
        <textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

$('#content').children().draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(id);
        console.log($(this));
        $('#textarea').val(id);
    }
});
```

outputs "foo"

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because you are not finding the id of `$('#content')`, but of the child div, which does *not* have an id set. Thus, give the child an ID and it will find that one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `$(this)` use `$("#content")`
Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pX2T4/4/