# How to get the <select> id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Walking through HTML form elements with jquery script, I see that I'm able to get the tag's id with this code:

```
$(":checkbox,:radio,:text,:selected", this).each(function(){
    var controlName = $(this).attr("id");
    var controlType = $(this).attr("type");

    alert(controlName);

    if(controlType=="checkbox" || controlType=="radio"){
        if ($(this).attr('checked')=="checked"){cadena += "&" + controlName + "=on";}
        else{ cadena += "&" + controlName + "=off";}    
    }
    else{
        cadena += "&" + controlName + "=" + $(this).attr('value');
    }               
});
```

It works with checkboxes, radioButtons and textInputs, giving me the right ids. But for select tags it always return "undefined".

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

*** UPDATE ***
This is my current form. I know that it is not a "normal" form, but I'm using it in a special application. Thanks to everybody for your patience:

```
    <form action="#" id="ejemplo" class="ejemplo">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Formulario de ejemplo </legend>

        <input id="Nombre" type="text" value="Texto1" name="Nombre" />    <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label> <br/>
        <input id="Apellidos" type="text" value="Texto1"  name="Apellidos" /> <label for="Apellidos">Apellidos</label> <br/>

        <label for="campo2">Campo 2</label>
        <select id="coches">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>

        <br/>

        <input type="checkbox" id="option1"> <label for="option1"> Milk   </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option2"> <label for="option2"> Butter </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option3"> <label for="option3"> Cheese </label>
        <br/>

        <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio1"> <label for="radio1"> Milk   </label> <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio2"> <label for="radio2"> Butter </label> <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio3"> <label for="radio3"> Cheese </label>
        <br/>

        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" id="areaTexto">Inside de text area!</textarea>
        <br/>
        <input id="boton" type="button" value="Boton"><br>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Getting the select "coche" id, it returns "undefined". But getting its value return the correct one.

After run My code it returns that:

&Nombre=Texto1&Apellidos=Texto1&undefined=volvo&option1=off&option2=off&option3=off&radio1=off&radio2=off&radio3=off

Look at undefined=volvo :S

Comment: You're not targeting select elements, but I guess the `:selected` selector would include options with that property

Comment: selects don't have "values". they have .selectedIndex. You can use jquery.val() to retrieve the selected option.

Comment: You can simply  use $(":input").each(function(){

Comment: With the posted code, controlName works for all elements, excluding select tags. For my select id it returns "undefined", but .attr('value') returns the rigth value for the select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:selected is not what you think it is.

> **[jQuery :select](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)**
>
> Description: Selects all elements that are selected.
>
> version added: 1.0
>
> `jQuery( ":selected" )` The :selected selector works for 
>   elements. It does not work for checkboxes or radio inputs; use
>   :checked for them.

You want to use `select` to get the select elements.

OR you can use [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) which gets all the input elements.

Comment: Finally, ":input" selector was what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[`:selected` matches selected `<option>`s](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), not `<select>` elements. Change the selector:

```
$(":checkbox,:radio,:text,select", this)
```

**N.B.** [`$(this).attr('id')` can always be replaced with `this.id`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651923/139010)

Comment: Matt, changing $(this).attr('id') by this.id as you say always return "undefined". Your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @CesarOrtiz or you're selecting elements that don't have IDs.

Comment: Maybe. Let me try more options. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="foo">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

for select tags you can use the `:selected` filter, to get id of select option's parent:

```
var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
```

Comment: .attr('rel') always return "undefined" :(

Comment: $(this).find('option:selected').val(); will return the value of the selected option

Comment: Getting the select value is not the issue. I can get it without problems. What I can't get is the select id. Thanks

Comment: here: var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");