# $(this).find("p").text() vs $("p", $(this)).text() in jQuery considering speed

Tags: jquery, performance

If I have a simple HTML layout like this:

```
<div class="items">
    <p>Some text #1</p>
</div>
.
.
<div class="items">
    <p>Some text #n</p>
</div>
```

Which approach of the below two is considered better (if any at all) in terms of speed (if I for the sake of argument have `n` around 10k) when wanting to iterate over all the divs and then fetching the text of the paragraph:

```
#1.Approach
$(".items").each(function() {
    var p = $(this).find("p").text();
    //do stuff with p
});

#2.Approach
$(".items").each(function() {
    var p = $("p", $(this)).text();
    //do stuff with p
});
```

Comment: `$("p", $(this))` should really be `$("p", this)` which is [shorthand](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) for `$(this).find("p")`.  They are *equivalent*.

Comment: If you're doing it any less than several thousand times at once, the actual speed difference will be negligible.

Comment: See for yourself: http://jsperf.com/this-vs-find

Comment: Avoid the find alltogether. `$(".items p")` it will be far faster than .find when dealing with 10k elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use Vanilla JavaScript vs. jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery)

Comment: @NULL: How is it a duplicate?

Comment: @tymeJV: great, thanx, I'm shamefully admiting I didn't know about jsperf, so thank you for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool, I reckon you are looking for `.find` method vs `context method`

check this (*since you are keen*)

- http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel/61
- http://jsperf.com/children-vs-find-vs-context

The context gets translated to the `.find` so if you want to avoid that use `.find`

Rest the jspref will show you the performance.

Hope it fits your need. `:)` although both calls are same.