# Save chrome extension options to chrome.storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that has an *options.html* page.

On the options page I have 3 checkboxes. When one of the checkboxes is checked/unchecked the value of that checkbox is saved to- or removed from chrome.storage using *chrome.storage.sync.set()*. But I can't seem to retrieve the data once it is saved using *chrome.storage.sync.get()*.

Here's the code I have:

**options.html:**

```
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input id="test1" name="test1" type="checkbox">       
    <input id="test2" name="test2" type="checkbox">
    <input id="test3" name="test3" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

**options.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var storage = chrome.storage.sync;

  //Retrieve existing settings
  $(':checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', function() {
      var name = this.name;
      storage.get(name, function(test){
        console.log(test[name]);
      });
    });
  });

  $(".checkboxes").on("change", ":checkbox", saveSettings);

  //Save or delete settings
  function saveSettings() {
    var name = this.name;   

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      storage.set({name:'checked'},function(){
        console.log("saved");
      });
    }
    else {
      storage.remove(name, function(){
        console.log("removed");
      });
    }
  }

});
```

**Above outputs:**

```
console.log(test[name]); > undefined
console.log("saved");    > saved
console.log("removed");  > removed
```

Why do I get "undefined"?

I tired the same thing using *localStorage* which worked fine on only *option.js*. But when I tried to retrieve the stored data on *background.js* it didn't work. I figured their *localStorage* details are not accessible to each other.

I should also mention I'm not the best at javascript/jquery and I'm still learning, so please excuse my mistakes.

Comment: Are you sure you get undefined for the checkboxes that should be checked ? It is normal to get undefined for those that have been unchecked (and thus removed from storage).

Comment: I recently wrote a module that auto-saves the whole options form: [webext-options-sync](https://github.com/fregante/webext-options-sync). You could try that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got two main issues:

1. [`chrome.storage.sync.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get) is asynchronous, while the function in [`jQuery.fn.prop(propertyName, function(index, oldPropertyValue) )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex--oldPropertyValue) must synchronously return the desired value.
2. `storage.set({name:'checked'}, ...);` will create a property called "name" with value "checked", *not* a property with the name as specified in the `name` variable with value "checked".

To solve the first problem, swap the order of operations: First read the preference, *then* set the property:

```
//Retrieve existing settings
$(':checkbox').each(function(index, element) {
    var name = this.name;
    storage.get(name, function(items) {
        element.checked = items[name]; // true  OR  false / undefined (=false)
    });
});
```

To solve the second issue, first create an object, assign the new property, and save the result. Note: Since a checkbox can only have two states, I recommend to not save the string "checked", but use a boolean (true / false):

```
function saveSettings() {
    var name = this.name;
    var items = {};
    items[name] = this.checked;
    storage.set(items, function() {
        console.log("saved");
    });
}
```

PS. When you're certain that you're dealing with checkboxes, use `element.checked` instead of `$(element).is(':checked')`. The former is shorter and faster. Using jQuery adds no value here. See also: [When to use Vanilla JavaScript vs. jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery)