# What's the fastest selector

Tags: jquery

Just trying to improve my selector. I have a lot of rows, but i need to exclude rows that has "table_row valuetemplate" class.

```
<table>      
    <tr class="table_row"></tr>
    <tr class="table_row"></tr>
    <tr class="table_row"></tr>
    <tr class="table_row valuetemplate"></tr>
</table>
```

I know this very fast :

```
$(".table_row")
```

This one is much slower:

```
$(".table_row:not(.valuetemplate")
```

Is this the only way to exclude?

Comment: Is the one with the class always at the end?

Comment: you should use jsperf.com to bench the selectors.

Comment: @patrick No it's not always at the end.

Comment: You will find the complete information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214/good-ways-to-improve-jquery-selector-performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(".table_row:not(.valuetemplate)")` appears to be fastest (tested in Chrome 13 & FF 5, results from Chrome)

http://jsperf.com/not-jquery-selectors

`$(".table_row").not('.valuetemplate')`

- 17,977 operations/sec
- ±0.13%
- 29% slower

`$(".table_row:not(.valuetemplate)")`

- 25,386
- ±1.89%
- fastest

`$("table").children(":not(.valuetemplate)");`

- 17,894
- ±0.36%
- 30% slower

Comment: What about other browsers? E,g IE?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".table_row").not(".valuetemplate");
```

I am not sure if it's any faster, but I know as a jQuery best practice that using methods instead of specialized selectors is usually faster. *Edit: but not in this case*.

For example:

```
$(".thing .subthing")
```

is a lot slower than

```
$(".thing").find(".subthing");
```

Comment: This does not seem to be true in this case. According to [this jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/which-not), `:not()` runs faster than `.not()` (as tested on Chrome 13).