# Which way to use a jQuery selector is better when it comes to performace?

Tags: jquery, performance

I am in the process of optimizing the JavaScript code used on our site and need some pointers/tips on what to do and what not to. We use jQuery 1.7.1 as our library.

When it comes to optimizing/writing an optimized code, I am still a novice, but what I do know is that we need to reduce the number of DOM traversals.

So, what I am thinking about is to cache the elements used more often and then use the cached elements for whatever reasons.

What I am confused or should say am curious about, how about if on DOM ready, I cache the "body" element in a variable of global scope and then use it in all JavaScript code/files to find any element(s) I may need there after.

like

```
jQuery(function(){
    myGlobalObj.body = jQuery('body');

    ..
    ..
    ..
    myGlobalObj.body.find('.someElement').<whatever>;
    ..
    ..
    ..
    myGlobalObj.body.find('#someOtherElement').<whatever>;
    ..
    ..
    ..

});
```

Will it prove to be useful for improving performance?
Are there any adverse effects, like not getting updated DOM tree, or something?

Please advice.

Edit #1: Thanks for the comments and answers guys, but I guess I did not make myself clear.

I know the benefit of using an ID based selector over the one with a className, but what my concern was that will performance increase by using a cached reference of "body" (or the closest filtered parent of the searched element) for searching/isolating the target elements.

i.e. instead of using $(..whateverElement..) every-time,

will $cachedParent.find(..whateverElement..) prove to be a better performer or not?

Comment: There are plenty of websites explaining jquery perf improvement techniques. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214/good-ways-to-improve-jquery-selector-performance

Answer (score 2):

`$("#id")` is very much more efficient than `$(".class")` -- the `$(".class")` will iterate through the entire set.

a good way to vet this is :

```
var yourElement = $(".class");
for (var i=0; i< yourElement.length; i++)
 { alert(i);}
```

`$("#id")` will return and run on only that one element (the first occurrence if there are improperly multiple id's with the same value even).

Edit: It additionally gets a little convoluted when the `.children()` and `.parent()` functions are used. These are related to what Jorge has mentioned below regarding the available arguments to the jquery selector native (and perform mostly the same)

@ Jorge - good observation

Answer (score 1):

`$('#id')` is the fastest way to do this

And you can save references for reuse later

`var $cache = $('.cache');`

Answer (score 1):

Just `$('.someElement')` and `$('#someOtherElement')` will be much better than using `.find` as it uses native `getElementsByClassName(..)` and `getElementById(..)` native methods.

[Proof](http://jsperf.com/find-vs-idv2)