# jQuery attr() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery function `attr()` to fetch a input element' custom attribute. However this function returns `undefined` in Chrome. I tried to print this element and the result is:

```
[prevObject: o.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "input[name="money",uid="1"]", jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function…]
```

Following are my js codes:

```
$('.panel').each(function(index, element) {
    var uid = $(this).attr('uid');
    console.log($(this));
    var moneyMinusBtn = $(this).find('.btn-money-minus')[0];
    var moneyPlusBtn = $(this).find('.btn-money-plus')[0];
    var moneyInput = $(this).find('input[name="money"]')[0];
    console.log($('input[name="money",uid="'+uid+'"]').attr('uid'));
}
```

HTML code:

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="money" value="<?php echo $node['money'] ?>" uid="1" />
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem? I'm not sure why it's not working, but you shouldn't use custom attributes in the first place, you should use `data-XXX` attributes.

Comment: a) there's no `uid` attribute in HTML b) your `input[name="money",uid="1"]` selector is invalid c) the collection is therefore probably empty

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the way you're chaining the attribute selectors. This will work:

```
$('input[name="money"][uid="'+uid+'"]').attr('uid')
```

It might also be a good idea to use data-* attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the rendered HTML to make sure that PHP wrote right values, but anyway, I think you cannot require two attributes in the way you showed:

```
$('input[name="money",uid="'+uid+'"]')
```

Try changing it into:

```
$('input[name="money"][uid="'+uid+'"]')
```

<s>Or even (might be faster selector, otherwise the same):</s>

```
$('input').filter('[name="money"][uid="'+uid+'"]')
```

Note there is no space or separator of any kind between `[name="money"]` and `[uid="'+uid+'"]`.

See comments for performance discussion.

Comment: Judging from a quick performance test I'd say that the filter method will be slower: http://jsperf.com/attribute-selector-or-filter

Comment: Interesting. it used to be agreed that selecting by tag name is much faster ( highly voted example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214/good-ways-to-improve-jquery-selector-performance ), so, I made it first since jQuery (Sizzel) evaluates right to left.
I guess the reason it's faster is that `uid` matches a single element directly, and the browser has `querySelectorAll` will have attribute selector optimized already. This won't be the case in a browser that doesn't if you care about old IE for example.

Comment: Either Way, I have modified the answer to point to the comments instead.