# Element + ID vs only ID in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, dom, htmlelements

`div#some_id` will scan through all the divs throughout the DOM.

`#some_id` will pick up the ID directly from the DOM.

So which is faster? `$('div#some_id')` or `$('#some_id')`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good ways to improve jQuery selector performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214/good-ways-to-improve-jquery-selector-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ID are supposed to be unique in DOM, so `div#some_id` will be doing unnecessary scan on all DOM elements and `#some_id` will do a direct scan on it.

You can also see the result here: [div-some-id-vs-some-id](http://jsperf.com/div-some-id-vs-some-id)

Comment: The link really helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See [Optimize Selectors](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/):

> Beginning your selector with an ID is always best.

and

> ID-only selections are handled using document.getElementById(), which is extremely fast because it is native to the browser.

So the answer is: $('#some_id') should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a simple test here in the console. It seems just using #id is faster as @Ulli said. Here is the test code:

```
var perf = performance;

var a = perf.now(); $("#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM795:2 0.03399999695830047
undefined
var a = perf.now(); $("#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM796:2 0.0329999893438071
undefined
var a = perf.now(); $("#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM797:2 0.0329999893438071
undefined
var a = perf.now(); $("#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM798:2 0.03500000457279384
undefined
var a = perf.now(); $("div#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM799:2 0.07000000914558768
undefined
var a = perf.now(); $("div#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM800:2 0.06600000779144466
undefined
var a = perf.now(); $("div#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM801:2 0.0680000230204314
undefined
var a = perf.now(); $("div#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM802:2 0.06799999391660094
undefined
var a = perf.now(); $("div#custom-header"); console.log(perf.now() - a);
VM803:2 0.06799999391660094
undefined
```

Comment: No need to accept this answer just wanted to post the test.

Comment: Your explanation helps @Syd. :)